# Django - manage model instances like in a pseudo files system

Tags: django

I would like to have a pseudo file system that will allow user to create directories, move model instances from a directory to another, and all other basics functions, from an html page all in django.

I want to display directories and instances in an html table (im using django-tables2 for this). I am not looking for a real files manager plugin because I want everything to stay in the database.

Does a plugin already exists for such purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filesystem is just a tree, so you could store your models using some sort of tree/heirarchy structure (this could be as simple as a foreign key from a model to itself)

https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

MPTT might not be exactly what you are looking for but the above link provides some background on the issue that needs to be solved storing hierarchical data in a rdbms

(from the above link):

- [Trees in SQL](http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/DBMSTrees/sqltrees.html)
- [Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://www.sitepoint.com/print/hierarchical-data-database)
- [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/mysql/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html)

Comment: Great info thank you! I did'nt know tree hierarchy was the terms to look for.